# Imports within a project from a repo

Tags: github, path, python-import

I wondered if there is a smoother way to work with modules pulled from a repo than extending the path with sys.path.extension.

We pull a project and need to save the file structure of it for every day once completed. Besides, I pull the whole project every time I start to work.

The path extensions needed are differently deep and we just use a lot of lines of code to describe locations of modules.

Is there an easier way to do this? Is there a way to generalize this path extensions?

We push and pull the repo quite often and since we are talking about a small collection of scripts we always pull the whole master(project) to work locally. So setting up the project's path extensions once locally to run does not solve the problem of the next day.

```py
str_rel_par_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
sys.path.extend([os.path.join(str_rel_par_folder, r'some_file')])
```

It would be very nice if someone knows this problem and handles it somehow. Maybe you have some recommendation on how to use Github differently to avoid those kinds of issues.

Answer (score 0):

So I came to the following insights how to handle this issue efficiently:

1. The easiest way is to structure the project in a way that no import needs to be take place from a higher level than the script that runs the import. This is probably self-explaining to someone with a deeper technical knowledge than me.
2. In case there is no way to structure the project differently than with imports from higher and lower levels one can always add the project path to the PATH/PYTHONPATH. This is no recommended because it causes problems and conflicts when you try to run your script on another machine.